# Android Studio build Error:'Failed to resolve shimmer-android-release ' and 'Failed to resolve libuvccamera-release'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I was building an Android open source project '**Tower-develop**' yesterday by the Android Studio, it made two errors like this:

[image]

My gradle's version is 2.10
My Android Studio version is 2.10

Comment: check two things : first in your build.gradle is there define  shimmer and libuvcamera in dependencies . second: is there this libs include in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Create a folder within folder Tower-develop. It should be called shimmer-android-release.
   [Folder project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mbkq.png)
2. Copy the  "shimmer-android-release.aar" file into the folder created.
3. Create a file into "shimmer-android-release" folder. It should be called build.gradle.
4. Enter the following text in the file "build.gradle".
   [Library folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfWfn.png)

> ```
>   configurations.create("default")
>   artifacts.add("default", file('shimmer-android-release.aar'))
> ```

5. Enter the following text in the "settings.gradle file. [Setting][3]

> ```
>   include ':shimmer-android-release'
> ```

6. Enter the following text in the "build.gradle" file that is inside the folder Android.[dependences Android Studio][4]

> ```
>   compile project(':shimmer-android-release')
> ```

Sorry my English.